# JS replace only text without html tags and codes

Tags: javascript, replace

I want to replace some words of the document without changing any html tags or js codes.

Basically what I do is;

`document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('lorem','new lorem');`

But this code will replace any 'lorem'. I want to avoid tags like; `<script... var lorem = 123;  <div class="lorem", <a id="lorem"` etc.

How can I do this in JS?

Answer (score 5):

Walk the DOM, and `.replace()` the values of text nodes.

```
function walk(el, fn) {
    for (var i = 0, len = el.childNodes.length; i < len; i++) {
        var node = el.childNodes[i];
        if (node.nodeType === 3)
            fn(node);
        else if (node.nodeType === 1 && node.nodeName !== "SCRIPT")
            walk(node, fn);
    }
}
```

---

```
walk(document.body, function(node) {
    var text = node.data.split("foo"),
        parent = node.parentNode,
        i = 1,
        newNode;

    parent.insertBefore(textNode(text[0]), node);

    for (; i < text.length; i += 2) {
        (newNode = document.createElement("b"))
                           .appendChild(textNode("bar"));
        parent.insertBefore(newNode, node);
        parent.insertBefore(textNode(text[i]), node);
    }
    parent.removeChild(node);
});

function textNode(txt) {
    return document.createTextNode(txt);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works great. There is only one thing, I can't work html tags with replace. I want to do replace(/foo/g, "<b>bar</b>"); but it doesn't affect because of node.data

Comment: @kentilyuk: I thought you didn't want to replace any elements. The DOM is not a string, so no, that won't work. What do you actually need to do?

Comment: I want to find 'foo' and change it with or without html tags like 'bar', '<b>bar</b>', '<span class="cname">bar</span>', '<a href="#">bar</a>' etc.

Comment: @kentilyuk: So you're saying you want to wrap the matched text in an element? Again, the DOM is not a string. We won't be using `HTML` markup to accomplish this.

Comment: Yes. That's what I try to do.

Comment: Updated code doesn't work. It worked before adding textNode function; `<p>foo is something foo</p>` to `<p><b> is something </b></p>` which was not true. After adding textNode nothing happens.

Comment: @kentilyuk: Had a typo and another mistake. Try again.

Comment: Here how it works; 
`<script type="text/javascript">
var <b>bar</b> = '';
</script>

<p><b>bar</b> is something </p>` It changed the js code and one of the foo words is missing in p tag.

Comment: @kentilyuk: Then test for  `node.nodeName == "SCRIPT"`  before making the recursive `walk` call.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is using regular expressions, science you can't insert HTML tags to a text node.

First I am using a regular expressions to catch parts of the body.innerHTML property that are outside of the HTML tags.

But, the string contains also another data, and if I will directly replace it with thge new data some text will be lost.

Insted, I get each match as an argument for a function, and inside this function I use another regular expression.

Notice that you have to replace "foo" twice.

The code:

`document.body.innerHTML=document.body.innerHTML.replace(/<[^(script)][^>]*>[^<]*(foo)[^<]*</g,function(match){
    return match.replace(/foo/,"newWord");
});`

Comment: This code changes not only text but also js codes. I have <script tag in body. And it turned like this; <script type="text/javascript">
var <b>bar</b> = '';