# Replace one text with another in a tag containing other tags

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML element:

```
<p id="myP">Some text<span onclick="myFunc()"> to change</span></p>
```

My idea is to replace "Some text" with "Some other text" when someone clicks on the "to change" span. So my first try was:

```
function myFunc(){
    var myP = document.getElementById("myP");
    myP.innerText = "Some other text";
}
```

... However, I have already learned [from my mistakes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27479449/3111149) that this would over-ride not only the text, but also the span element nested in the p. So, using the learning of the last time, I've tried to rather create a text node:

```
function myFunc(){
    var myP = document.getElementById("myP");
    myP.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Some other text"));
}
```

However this is clearly wrong, because it would **append** the text and not replace it. How should I write my JavaScript function to obtain the pure replacement of *Some text* with *Some other text*, without however affecting the nested span?

I know this might seem a basic question, but I'm a complete beginner and don't know how well yet how to treat with HTML objects. Thanks in advance

**NOTE** I think that I could do simply this:

```
myP.innerText = "Some other text<span onclick="myFunc()"> to change</span>"
```

... but apart for being complicated because this is a minimized example w.r.t. the real code, I imagine it's the most unelegant solution ever, so I would like to learn the proper way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JS replace only text without html tags and codes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919074/js-replace-only-text-without-html-tags-and-codes)

Comment: @PaulRoub, in my modest opinion the question you indicate as duplicate is not exactly the same cause it wants to replace an attribute only on certain elements. Moreover, the question you say has no answer while here users have made efforts to provide high-quality answers (always in my modest opinion) :)

Comment: You've misread the other question; it's trying to *avoid* replacing attributes, among other things. And the top-rated answer there (unlike the accepted answer here) will still work if `"Some text"` shows up (a) more than once or (b) *after* the `span` tag. I had assumed you were looking for something slightly more general, but apparently I was mistaken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just get the textNode

```js
function myFunc(){
  var myP = document.getElementById("myP").firstChild;
  myP.nodeValue = "Some other text";
}
```

```html
<p id="myP">Some text<span onclick="myFunc()"> to change</span></p>
```

Comment: Thank you @adeneo, this is definitely the approach I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just implement it using another element?

```
<p><span id="to-change">Some text</span> <span onclick="myFunc()">to change</span></p>
```

```js
function myFunc(){
    document.getElementById("to-change").innerText = "Some other text";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a "strategic" approach so I cannot deny you an upvote! However, I prefer the solution to point to the object, it doesn't expect any HTML revision. Thanks a lot anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can replace the first text node with a new one:

```js
function myFunc() {
    var myP = document.getElementById("myP");
    myP.replaceChild(document.createTextNode("Some other text"), myP.childNodes[0]);
}
```

```html
<p id="myP">Some text<span onclick="myFunc()"> to change</span></p>
```

Comment: Thank you dfsq, I upvote your question cause it's my favorite solution, but for sake of timing I'm accepting adeneo's, who told the same thing :)

Answer (score 1):

For the *really* simple approach:

```js
function myFunc(){
    var myP = document.getElementById("myP");
    var cn = myP.childNodes[0]; // where cn.nodeType == 3 (text node)
    cn.textContent = "Some other text";
}
```

```html
<p id="myP">Some text<span onclick="myFunc()"> to change</span></p>
```

Comment: Thank you Brad, I appreciate it. Just for sake of timing I'm accepting adeneo's answer, he wrote the same thing a few second before :) thanks a lot!